# Django: M2M database annotation query

Tags: django, database

Given the following models:

```
User
--------

Thread
--------

Post
--------
thread: ForeignKey(Thread)
read_by: ManyToManyField(User)
```

Now, I would like to retrieve all posts for a specific thread annotated if they are read by the currently logged in user.

So, I start with fetching the posts:

```
Post.objects.filter(thread=self.thread)
```

Now, I am not sure how I can annotate with the read/unread flag set to True/False. The currently logged in user is available using the variable `self.request.user`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can make an `EXISTS` subquery here, by querying the "through" model Django constructed implicitly:

```
from django.db.models import Exists, OuterRef

post_read_query = Post.ready_by.through.objects.filter(
    user_id=self.request.user.pk,
    post_id=OuterRef('pk')
)
```

We then use this `post_read_query` in an [**`Exists`** subquery [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/expressions/#exists-subqueries):

```
Post.objects.filter(thread=self.thread).annotate(
    is_read=Exists(post_read_query)
)
```

The `Post` objects that arise from this will have an extra attribute `.is_read` that is `True` given the `Post` has been read by the user (`self.request.user`).

This will generate a query that looks like:

```
SELECT post.*,
    EXISTS(
        SELECT U0.id, U0.user_id, U0.post_id
        FROM post_read_by U0
        WHERE U0.post_id = post.id AND U0.user_id = user_id
    ) AS is_read
FROM post
WHERE post.thread_id = thread_id
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your detailed answer. I wouldn't have guessed that.